# Open firefox bookmark in private mode

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Can a bookmark be opened in a private tab by editing the bookmark location ?

On Reddit I seen a reference to prefix the bookmark link with `private:///#` :

https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/1zff4g/is_it_possible_to_set_a_bookmark_to_always_open_a/

But the extension link is broken. Is there a method to accomplish this behavior natively or via an extension ?

Answer (score 1):

The reference you saw was probably for the
[Private Bookmarks extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webext-private-bookmarks/).

Add the prefix `private:///#` to any URL and it will open in a private tab, example :

```
private:///#http://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/
```

Comment: thanks but after installing the extension and opening private:///#http://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/ a search window with the text "private:///#http://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/" is displayed. Seems the private:///# prefix is not been recognized. Did you have to change any other config after installing this extension ?

Comment: The doc talks about a new 'Private Bookmarks' folder that appears under 'Other Bookmarks', does it work from that folder (with or without the prefix of `private:///#`). Otherwise, maybe recent developments in Firefox have disabled this app, and then you would need to contact the developer.

Comment: the 'Private Bookmarks' folder has not been created, as you say perhaps it does not work with latest Firefox version.